# Poincare inequality on balls to general open subset

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $M$ be an n-dim compact Riemannian manifold with $Ric \geqslant -(n-1)$, it's well known that the following Poincare inequality holds for any function $f\in W^{1,2}(M)$
$$
(\int_B |f-\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B f|^2) \leqslant C r \int_B |\nabla f|^2
$$
For a function $f\in W^{1,2}(M)$ with $vol(M)>vol(Spt(f))$, where $Spt(f)$ is the support of $f$. Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $Spt(f)$, how can we get the following Poincare inequality for $U$?
$$
\int_U f^2 \leqslant C \int_U |\nabla f|^2
$$ 
If we use partion of unity, let $\varphi_i$ be the functions supported on balls $B_i$, such that $U\subset \cup B_i$. Then 
$$
|\nabla (\varphi_i f)|^2 \leqslant 2(|\nabla \varphi|^2 f^2+\varphi^2|\nabla f|^2)
$$

We still have $f^2$ on the right hand side.